# Search - can't switch back to relevance

Tags: search

I'm using magento 1.9.1.0. I found a issue:

My search type is Combined. On a search result, if I switch the sort order from relevance to price (for example), I'll see the items' order change. If I switch back to relevance, nothing changes. Is it a bug?